# Unit testing on Netty 4.1.6

Tags: java, junit, netty

I have finished developing a card game using `Netty 4.1.6` composed of a server and several clients.

I now wish to create some unit tests (that should have been created as I was coding the project). Some of them include: testing user input, testing server output etc.

I've read that I could create an `EmbeddedChannel` in order to mock it's actions like such:

```
 public void testNettyStringDecoder() {
    EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new StringDecoder(Charset.defaultCharset()));
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{(byte)0xE2,(byte)0x98,(byte)0xA2}));
    String myObject = channel.readInbound();

    assertEquals("☢", myObject);
    System.out.println("[NETTY] Tested our StringDecoder's ability to decode unicode." +
            " Expected ☢ got " + myObject);
}
```

But I now wish to mock a `ChannelHandlerContext` in order to test a fake clients input. How may I do that using `JUnit` ?

Answer (score 0):

EmbeddedChannel is just fine to work with codecs and pipelines and you do not need to mock `ChannelHandlerContext`. You can verify your business logic with unit test if you place your handler in channel and you can be sure that all necessary infrastructure for executing handler logic is in place.

Since each embedded channel represents a separate connection, you can have as many channels as you wish. If you channel handler is shareable  then you will be able to verify how it behaves with multiple channels open.

If embedded channel is not enough you can use `LocalAddress` and bootstrap fully functional server/client just for in-vm test.

Comment: I'm currently trying to unit test [HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java), but having trouble doing so using `EmbeddedChannel`. Can you elaborate on your last statement or suggest a way?